# Windows SASS speed

Tags: windows, sass, workflow, haml, erb

I was trying to make more professional and efficent webdev workflow and was amazed by SASS and template systems like ERB/HAML but there comes my main concern.

I get used to almost instant live refresh using LiveReload for vanilla HTML/CSS and SASS compile time is a little slow for me. SCSS file with one rule (for example - background color to red) is compiling ~3-5 seconds. I can only imagine what will happen with multiple imports/extends. ERB/HAML is much faster.

I've tried many options:

- Prepros
- LiveReload app
- Fire.app
- Yeoman (so manually installing ruby/grunt/git etc.)
- Mixture

In all of these, compiling time is different but never go less than 3 seconds for an almost empty file. I don't think my PC specs is a problem here (i5 760 @3.40, 8GB RAM).

Thanks in advance for any advice and also please, let me know what's your best Windows webdev environment. I'd like to make it as fast and as automated as possible.

Comment: How are you compiling sass?  I hadn't had any compile issues (seemed fast) when I was working on PC with sass.  All I did was create a batch file for each project with the 'sass --watch' command for the given project in it.  seemed to run smooth, and it was a considerably older computer than what you're running.

Comment: Here i3, 8gb ram. Via terminal in ubuntu and in win via cmd: almost instant. Using phpstorm/webstorm file watchers: 2-3 secs on both platforms.